# couchdb add document transformation — using updates function

Tags: couchdb

I have a updates method `updates/add-date.js`

```
function(oldDoc, req) {
    var newDoc = req.body;
    return [newDoc, toJSON({newDoc:newDoc,oldDoc:oldDoc})];
}
```

It gets put it to the design doc as.

```
"updates": {
       "add-date": "function(oldDoc, req) {\n    var newDoc = fromJSON(req.body);\n    return [newDoc, toJSON({newDoc:newDoc,oldDoc:oldDoc})];\n}"
},
```

I expect it to be a “do nothing”, when I do a put using it `"/db/_design/xyz/_update/add-date/"+value._id`, it should put the document as if we put it directly, but I get no change and this in the log:

```
PUT /q-couch-test/_design/couch-experiment/_update/add-removed-date/2601b8c4dad9648e8ddae3804f15e652 200
```

I expect status to be `201` not `200`, and no change is made to the document. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
"add-date": "function(oldDoc, req) {\n    var newDoc = oldDoc;\n    return [newDoc,      toJSON({newDoc:newDoc,oldDoc:oldDoc})];\n}"
```

First the fromJson gave an error when I tried to run your update function. Is it a built in couchDB function? I could not find anything about it when I googled it.

The `req.body` will contain the data that you send from the client. Where as the actual document is in the `oldDoc` itself.  Since you are "doing nothing" you could just set the `newDoc = oldDoc` and return it. Here are the headers that I got after the curl request to the modified update function

> HTTP/1.1 201 Created
>
> X-Couch-Update-NewRev: 3-97e66b27322db9deb7d03a32926488f0
>
> X-Couch-Id: 753ffdc034c3681616e5939d62000211
>
> Server: CouchDB/1.5.0 (Erlang OTP/R16B02)
>
> Date: Thu, 03 Apr 2014 06:37:57 GMT
>
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
>
> Content-Length: 431

If you try to update the document to a null value it is equivalent to

`return[null,doc]`

in which case the document won't actually be updated and you just get a 200 ok response. From [the wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_Update_Handlers)

> The handler function takes the most recent version of the document from the database and the http request environment as parameters. It returns a two-element array: the first element is the (updated or new) document, which is committed to the database. If the first element is null no document will be committed to the database.

Comment: When I say do nothing, I did not mean “do not update the document”, I mean update it as if there was no update function. (this is point less, why have an update function you may ask. It is so I have a base to do something useful. If I can't do this, then I can't write any useful update function.) I will try your code any why, as it will give insight.

Comment: @richard yes that is exactly what it is doing. I might have explained it poorly in the answer but it basically just updates the document with the old document. You can test it by getting all the rev_info of the document. `http://localhost:5984/your_db/your_doc_id?revs_info=true`. Let me know if it works.

Comment: No you explained it fine it is me that has explained it badly. It is my definition of “do nothing”, I do not mean to keep the document unchanged. What I mean is to update the document as if I had not installed an update function.